# MQTT with Angular

Tags: angular, mqtt, mqtt.js

I am trying to receive some mqtt messages in my Angular Application.
Unfortunately, it does not work.
Here is my Code (I followed this: https://sclausen.github.io/ngx-mqtt/):
In app.module.ts:

```
import {
  IMqttMessage,
  MqttModule,
  IMqttServiceOptions,
  MqttService
} from 'ngx-mqtt';

export const MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS: IMqttServiceOptions = {
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 9001,
  path: '/mqtt'
};
```

In app.component.ts:

```
  subscription: Subscription | undefined;
  constructor(private mqttService: MqttService) {
    this.serial = new NgxSerial(this.dataHandler);
    console.log(mqttService)
    this.subscription = this.mqttService.observe('my/topic').subscribe((message: IMqttMessage) => {
      this.message = message.payload.toString();
      console.log('Received message:', message.payload.toString());
    });
  }


  public unsafePublish(topic: string, message: string): void {
    this.mqttService.unsafePublish(topic, message, { qos: 1, retain: true });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

Here are my tries to send messages to the application:

[image]

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: What errors if any do you get in the browser console? Have you configured mosquitto to listen for websocket connections on port 9001?

Comment: I do not have any errors, here is my config file: `listener 1883
protocol mqtt
listener 9001
protocol websockets
allow_anonymous true`

Comment: Do you see the connection from the browser in the mosquitto logs?

Comment: Unfortunately when I try to add logs I get this: ```1699880843: Error: Unable to open log file "C:\mosquitto.txt" for writing.```

Comment: No need to write logs to file, if you run the broker on the command line it will log to stdout by default.

Comment: i get the browser-client ```1699881743: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:53868 as client-ht6litei8f5 (p2, c1, k60).```

Comment: "i get the browser-client" - and do you also seen the SUBSCRIBE? (you may need to set `log_type all` in `mosquitto.conf`). Including a log showing the client connecting and then you sending a test message would be helpful (please edit the question to add this detail rather than adding it in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

then in app.module.ts I advise you not to put the parameters to connect, but only the code structure.

And then in a component you can put all the logic. Tell me if you have already solved otherwise I help you.